# Automatically Load or embed a folder of assets

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, load, assets

I'm trying to find a way to automatically load several assets into my project made in AS3.

Scenario: I have 135 .png files I need to load, I have a ResourceManager class that can load this through embeds or loaders, nothing new. There is a little problem, I need to provide every single name (../assets/myImage.png) everytime I make an embed/loader. I dont want to.

Is there a way to specify a path, and somehow, automatically load every single file that ends in, let say, .png?.

I was thinking on making a .bat program that makes a list of files ending in .png, wich could make a .txt file, and then using AS3, just loop throught that file and make the asset loading using the Loader class.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using AIR? if so then you can scan a folder.  Otherwise, you'll have either do what you suggest, or use a predictable naming convention.  eg  photo1.png, photo2.png, photo3.png, then you can just cycle through them with a loader dynamically until you get to the last number. If you don't know the last number, but are sure that there are no gaps in numbers, you can listen for the first IOError and stop loading then.

Comment: No, I'm using flash to make a website.

Comment: are you or do you have the option of using a server side scripting language?  (eg. asp/php/jsp etc).  I ask because if web is your delivery, your can use the server to scan the folder and pass on the list of assets to the swf file when it loads it.

Comment: Sure, I could do a php rutine to deliver that info to my swf I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use a server script such as PHP to return a formatted xml file, such as in this tutorial: [folder content in xml file](http://www.php-help.ro/php-tutorials/output-folder-content-in-xml-file/)

Then you'll just have to read that file and load in the files.

I often use the [BulkLoader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/) class to assist in loading multiple assets like this.

```
var xmlContentList:XML = [THE LOADED XML FILE FROM THE PHP];
var imageLoader:BulkLoader = new BulkLoader("image-loader");
for (var imageNode:XML in xmlContentList..image)
{
    imageLoader.add( imageNode.path );
}
imageLoader.addEventListener(BulkLoader.COMPLETE, onAllLoaded);
imageLoader.start();
```

Comment: That seems really useful, Im going with that option.